# Multiple AND in WHERE via SELECT Query | SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: php, html, xampp, sqlsrv

I understand that AND clause has a limit, I wonder why this query wont work?

```
SELECT
physicianmasterfile.idno,
physicianmasterfile.lastname,
physicianmasterfile.firstname,
physicianmasterfile.middlename,
physicianmasterfile.fingerscanno,
YEAR(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) AS Year,
MONTH(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) AS Month,
CONVERT(TIME(0),CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) AS Time

FROM 
physicianmasterfile,
CHECKINOUT 

WHERE  
CHECKINOUT.userid=physicianmasterfile.fingerscanno AND
MONTH(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) = MONTH(SYSDATETIME()) AND /* yields result in month(int) */
DAY(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) = DAY(SYSDATETIME()) AND /* yields result in day(int) */
YEAR(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) = YEAR(SYSDATETIME()) AND/* yields result in month(int) */
CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE='I'
```

When I tried to remove one of the `AND`, the query runs without a problem, but when there's 5 `AND` query, it yield no result upon execution.

Is there another way to do this without encountering errors?

I'm trying to get the value of `SYSDATETIME()` It yields a value of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:MS `2019-07-22 09:25:31.9557058`. Is there a way to get only the month, date, and the year, and separate the time? The data that I'm comparing to like this `2015-07-27 08:00:01.000`, The query should display only all the data in `2019-07-22`.

EDIT: Sample Data

`CHECKTIME : 2015-07-27 08:00:01.000`

Comment: While there may be a limit to how many terms can be `AND`ed together, 5 is nowhere near what that limit might be.  The problem is with your data and how you are interpreting/expecting it.  Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sample data added in edit. The rest of the query is okay, only the ````CHECKTIME```` part as i need to compare the data to the current timestamp (exuding the time). I only need to compare ````2015-07-27```` vs current timestamp. (YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: That sample data won't really help.  What we had in mind was sample data for both tables, along with the expected output.  Sample data is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Your current `WHERE` clause, while unwieldy, should in fact already be comparing just the year, month, and day.  So the problem may lie somewhere else.

Comment: Apologies for this matter guys, it's pure stupidity on my part, I'm comparing the current date from my test data (June 2019), obviously no record would be shown for 7/22/2019 as the data is from 6/20/2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try converting the two `datetime`s (`checktime` and `sysdatetime()`) to dates alone - that truncates the time part off of them

```
... AND CONVERT(DATE, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) = CONVERT(DATE, SYSDATETIME())
```

or

```
... AND CAST(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME AS DATE) = CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is cleaner than my previous query. Apologies for this matter as well, it's pure stupidity on my part, I'm comparing the current date from my test data (June 2019), obviously no record would be shown for 7/22/2019 as the data is from 6/20/2019.

Answer (score 0):

Can use this to compare date (111 = YYYY/MM/DD)?

```
WHERE
   CHECKINOUT.userid=physicianmasterfile.fingerscanno AND
   CONVERT(TIME(0), CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME, 111) = CONVERT(TIME(0), SYSTDATEIME(), 111) AND
   CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE='I'
```

Comment: Apologies for this matter guys, it's pure stupidity on my part, I'm comparing the current date from my test data (June 2019), obviously no record would be shown for 7/22/2019 as the data is from 6/20/2019.